# How to get stream traffic size in WebRTC

Tags: javascript, html, stream, webrtc, traffic

How to get stream traffic size in WebRTC.
I want to traffic information in client javascript.

Wait for your answer.

Comment: What does the data looks like? What kind of traffic information do you want to extract? Please clarify.

Comment: I want to video, audio stream traffic size.
Data type: send stream size, receive stream size

Answer (score 3):

As I understand your question, you are looking for some stats of your WebRTC communication.
There is the `getStats()` function. You'll be able to retrieve some statistics of your streams (eg. packetsReceived, bytesSent, packetLoss, etc.)

W3C link : http://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc-stats/

Related code : https://www.npmjs.com/package/getstats